# How to know the suitable reading of その間 in a given sentence?

Tags: multiple-readings

Sometimes the reading is そのかん as in

> 「**その間【かん】**に彼は居なくなっていました」
>   "He disappeared in the meantime."

and sometimes the reading is そのあいだ as in

> 「母は忙しそうに料理をしていた。**その間【あいだ】**私はテレビを見ていた」
>   "Mother was busily cooking; in the meantime, I was just watching TV."

How to know the suitable reading of その間 in a given sentence ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both share the same meaning, but そのかん sounds formal and stiff, since it uses on-yomi. In speech, it's mainly used in formal greetings and such. そのかん would sound funny if used in inappropriate situations. When in doubt, you can stick to そのあいだ, which is safe in any situation.

Comment: In this sentence, too? 何時間【なんじかん】も電車【でんしゃ】を待【ま】つなら、その間【あいだ】に自宅【じたく】で仕事【しごと】をした方【ほう】が効率【こうりつ】が良【よ】さそうですよね

If you are going to wait for a train for hours, it would be more efficient to work at home during that time, wouldn't it?

https://www.asahi.com/articles/ASPBN4S9RPBFULEI008.html?iref=comtop_ThemeRightS_03

Comment: @NedReif Both Yes, かん and あいだ seem okay to me.